# How to style empty message in mat-menu?

Tags: angular

I try to style only the empty message (center, color red) in the menu.

but since I using `ng-template` I can't add class. any idea how to style the message?

[my code on stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpw5jz?file=src/app/menu-overview-example.ts)

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { of } from "rxjs";
/**
 * @title Basic menu
 */
@Component({
  selector: "menu-overview-example",
  template: `
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>

    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <ng-container *ngIf="(items$ | async) as items; else empty">
        <ng-container *ngIf="items.length; else empty">
          <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</button>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-menu>

    <ng-template #empty class="empty-message">no items!</ng-template>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .empty-message {
        color: red;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class MenuOverviewExample {
  items = of([]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `mat-menu-item`, `disableRipple` and `disabled`:

```
<ng-template #empty>
 <div mat-menu-item disableRipple disabled class="empty-message">no favs</div>
</ng-template>
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpw5jz-ahq9ny?file=src/app/menu-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, that you wrap your content inside your `<ng-template>` within a `span`

```
<ng-template #empty>
    <span class="empty-message">no items!</span>
</ng-template>
```

Its not possible to style a `<ng-template>`. You need to wrap the content with a container (or in this case in a simple `<span>`)

Comment: but the height and width of 100% not works. because of `mat-menu-content`. so it not be center in the menu container.